# Application installer does not respond when clicked?

Tags: install

I am trying to install an application from its .iso image file. I can successfully mount the .iso file, but when I click the installer, nothing pops up.

I am installing a relatively old version of a software. My guess is that my Mac OS version is too new to run the installer.

How does one usually fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In system preferences

security

change the download from to anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there usually a dialogue box that appears if the app isn't allowed?

Comment: @dwightk Yes, the window popped up and I did have clicked *Yes, trust.*